# Power analysis in a clinical trial

Tags: statistical-power

In a randomized clinical trial, is power analysis based on observed means of the treatment groups or true mean of the treatments groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the observed means, because you haven't observed anything by the time you calculate power and sample size, which is *before* you run the experiment, more precisely, when you budget and apply for funding. ("Post hoc power" is a fallacy, cf. [Hoenig & Heisey, 2001](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313001300339897).)

You cannot use the true means, because if you knew the true means, you would not run an experiment.

You should use an effect size (which includes the means, but also the variability) [you would be sorry to miss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1352+%5Bpower-analysis%5D+sorry). This requires substantive knowledge. Note that this number may be larger or smaller than numbers reported in previous publications. (Published effect sizes are also likely biased high because of publication bias. Another reason why a power analysis can be inspired by, but not rely solely on the literature.)